# Obtener un solo resultado en una consulta con left join, sum y group by

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Estoy buscando la manera mas fácil de poder obtener las sumas de los tipos de estados de las tareas de mi tabla MYSQL, el problema que tengo es que se repiten los ID de las tareas en la tabla `timeslices`, y si lo agrupo por tareas, entonces ya no me arroja un solo resultado que es realmente lo que quiero. Actualmente se que todavía hay cosas que se me escapan de MYSQL, es por eso que hago esta pregunta haber si con ella resuelvo mis dudas.

Expongo mi consulta a la tabla `TASK` (tareas):

```
 $queryTask  = $em->getRepository(Task::class)->createQueryBuilder('tk')
      ->select('SUM(case when tk.estado = \'PD\' then 1 else 0 end) pendiente')
      ->addSelect('SUM(case when tk.estado = \'P\' then 1 else 0 end) progreso')
      ->addSelect('SUM(case when tk.estado = \'F\' then 1 else 0 end) finalizada')
      ->leftJoin('tk.timeslices','tm','with','tk = tm.task')
      ->andWhere('date(tk.fechacomienzo) BETWEEN :from AND :to OR date(tm.startAt) 
         BETWEEN :from AND :to')->setParameter('from', $from_date_new)- 
         >setParameter('to',$to_date_new);

$queryTask->getQuery()->getArrayResult()
```

Con esta consulta obtengo 3 tareas pendientes, realmente son solo 2, ya que por lo que me suma otra id de la tarea de la tabla `timeslices` que sacó con este `WHERE` y además con el `OR`, según mi lógica estoy preguntado:

> sácame las tareas que tenga la fecha que selecciono en el campo
> `fechacomienzo` en la tabla tareas `o` que hayan vuelto a comenzar
> desde la tabla timeslice en la fecha `startAt`

```
->andWhere('date(tk.fechacomienzo) BETWEEN :from AND :to OR date(tm.startAt) 
             BETWEEN :from AND :to')->setParameter('from', $from_date_new)- 
             >setParameter('to',$to_date_new)
```

Entonces si lo agrupo con el ID de la tarea, ya no me arroja un solo resultado, si no que me arroja dos resultados, quiero decir dos array de resultados desde [Nerja](https://www.taxi-nerja.com/).

Entonces cómo puedo proceder para obtener un solo resultado y agrupado por tareas? ¿Es posible?

**Actualización:**

Estoy volviendo a revisar, y creo que me estoy haciendo un lio grande. No lo tengo claro.

Comment: Bienvenido @jcarlosweb te recomiendo utilizar [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1) donde podras incluir la estructura de de tus tablas con por lo menos 2 datos para cada 1 asi podriamos entender mejor lo que buscas y darte un respuesta mas acorde con tu interrogante!